# possibility to add context menu to contacts?

Tags: android, contextmenu, contacts

Is there any means of possibility to add a context or option menu to the default contact application. If not so, can we add additional fields to the contacts application.

In blackberry there is a concept of application menu repository to add menu to default (native) applications. Is there anything that matches this concept in blackberry.

Please let me know the suggestions.

Thanks & Regards,
NavaS.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any means of possibility to add a context or option menu to the default contact application.

No, sorry.

> If not so, can we add additional fields to the contacts application.

No, sorry. You can use the `ContactsContract` content provider or sync providers to store additional data about a contact, but you cannot attack another application and hack changes to its UI.

> Is there anything that matches this concept in blackberry.

No, sorry.

Comment: **You can use the ContactsContract content provider or sync providers to store additional data about a contact**  Can we add any type of data such as Notes etc or only we can add contact relevant information such as phone no and email. If we can add anytype means can u provide a sample code.